# Autonomous transaction analogue in ABAP

Tags: abap, opensql

I'm trying to commit DML update in a database table while the main program is still running without committing it as there may be errors in future and there might be a need to rollback it but the internal (saved) updates should stay.
Like in the Oracle autonomous transactions.

`Call function ... starting new task ...` or `Submit ... and return` don't work as they affect the main transaction.

Is there a way to start a nested database LUW and commit it without interrupting the main LUW?

Comment: Is it somehow possible to move the "nested update" in front of the "main update", like `prepare( ). COMMIT WORK. main( )` ? Having two transactions nested also means you're seeing two different database states depending on which transaction you are in.

Comment: You say "[aRFC] or Submit [...] don't work as they affect the main transaction", I don't agree, only `Submit` runs in the same database LUW, aRFC runs in its own database LUW. Please clarify if you want to continue discussing about aRFC. Note that ABAP SQL permits natively "Service Connections" so that to start different database LUWs in the same ABAP LUW (`CONNECTION` word in all ABAP SQL statements, with connection starting with name `R/3*`).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to do this with OpenSQL. But when you are using the [ADBC framework](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenadbc.htm), then each instance of the class `CL_SQL_CONNECTION` [operates within a separate database LUW](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenadbc_transaction.htm).

I would generally not recommend using ADBC unless you have to, because:

- You are now writing SQL statements as strings, which means you don't have compile-time syntax checking.
- You can't put variables into SQL code anymore. (OK, you *can*, but you *shouldn't*, because you are probably creating SQL injection vulnerabilities that way). You need to pass all the variables using `statement->set_param`.
- You are now writing NativeSQL, which means that you might inadvertently write SQL which can't be ported to other database backends.

Comment: "I am not aware of a way to do this with OpenSQL" wouldn't it be possible to create a secondary database connection to the primary DB? (not that this is a good idea though ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate function for saving your changes and you can call your function with **starting new task** mode like below.

```
  call function 'ZFUNCTION' starting new task 'SAVECHANGES'
   exporting
     param  = value.
```

Comment: The question says they already tried and it didn't work. "Call function starting new task or Submit and return don't work as they affect the main transaction."

Comment: @Philipp it is working. Maybe they have another problem.